# Keep getting NoClassDefFoundError while loading a class with URLClassLoader

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception, urlclassloader

Recently I'm creating something that have to load/unload external jar packages dynamically. I'm now trying to do this with `URLClassLoader`, but I keep getting `NoClassDefFoundError` while trying to make new instances.

It seems that the external class is loaded successfully since the codes in the constructor are executed, but `ClassNotFoundException` and `NoClassDefFoundError` still keep being thrown.

I made an small package that recreates the error and here are the codes:

The codes below are in `ExternalObject.class` ,which is put in a .jar file, that I'm trying to load dynamically:

```
package test.outside;

import test.inside.InternalObject;

public class ExternalObject
{
    private final String str;

    public ExternalObject()
    {
        this.str = "Creating an ExternalObject with nothing.";
        this.print();
    }

    public ExternalObject(InternalObject inObj)
    {
        this.str = inObj.getString();
        this.print();
    }

    public void print()
    {
        System.out.println(this.str);
    }
}
```

And the codes below are in `InternalObject.class`:

```
package test.inside;

public class InternalObject
{
    private final String str;

    public InternalObject(String s)
    {
        this.str = s;
    }

    public String getString()
    {
        return this.str;
    }
}
```

I tested the file with `Main.class` below:

```
package test.inside;

import java.io.File;
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;

import test.outside.ExternalObject;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            File externalJar = new File("F:\\Dev\\ext.jar");
            URLClassLoader uclTest = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{externalJar.toURI().toURL()});
            Class<?> clazz = uclTest.loadClass("test.outside.ExternalObject");

            InternalObject inObj = new InternalObject("Creating an ExternalObject with an InternalObject.");

            try
            {
                System.out.println("Test 1: Attempt to create an instance of the ExternalObject.class with an InternalObject in the constructor.");
                Constructor<?> conTest = clazz.getConstructor(InternalObject.class);
                ExternalObject extObj = (ExternalObject)conTest.newInstance(inObj);
            }
            catch(Throwable t)
            {
                System.out.println("Test 1 has failed. :(");
                t.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println();

            try
            {
                System.out.println("Test 2: Attempt to create an instance of the ExternalObject.class with a void constructor.");
                Constructor<?> conTest = clazz.getConstructor();
                ExternalObject extObj = (ExternalObject)conTest.newInstance();
            }
            catch(Throwable t)
            {
                System.out.println("Test 2 has failed. :(");
                t.printStackTrace();
            }

            uclTest.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Both `InternalObject.class` and `Main.class` are in a jar pack which is included in the classpath while launched.
And I got this in the console:
[Console output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Utr73.png)

As the codes `this.print()` in both constructors of `ExternalObject.class` are executed, I have really no idea what's wrong. Help! :(

UPDATE: Thank you wero!!! But I actually want to make an instance of `ExternalObject` for further usage such as accessing methods in it from other classes. Is there any way that I can return the created instance as an `ExternalObject`? Or I have to use `getMethod()` and `invoke()` to access the methods?

Sincerely, 
Zevin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Main` class references `ExternalObject` and therefore the compiled `Main.class` has a dependency on `ExternalObject`.

Now when you run `Main` and `ExternalObject` is only available in `ext.jar` but not in the classpath used to run `Main` the following happens:

The `uclTest` classloader successfully loads `ExternalObject` from `ext.jar`. Also creation succeeds (seen by the print statement in the constructor).

But what fails are the assignments to local variables `ExternalObject extObj`.
`Main` cannot use the loaded class `ExternalObject` since it is loaded by a different classloader. There is also no `ExternalObject` in the classpath of `Main` and you get a `NoClassDefFoundError`.

Your test should run without problems when you remove the two assignments `ExternalObject extObj = (ExternalObject)`.

Comment: Thank you! It works!
But I think I focused on the Exception too much. Actually I want to create an instance of ExternalObject for further usage. Is there any way to create one that I'm able to use normally, or I must use getMethod() and invoke() ?
Thanks!

Comment: @ZevinZenphZambori The code which uses `ExternalObject` must then also be loaded by your custom classloader.

Answer (score 1):

I think because there are two classLoaders involved, and you try to cast an object from a classLoader to an object from another class loader. But is just a guess.

Answer (score 1):

Hooray!! I just found a better way for my codes! What I did is creating an `abstract` class `ExternalBase.class` with all abstract methods I need, then inherit `ExternalObject.class` from `ExternalBase.class`. Therefore dynamically loaded class have to be neither loaded into the custom loader nor imported by the classes that use the object, and the codes work totally perfect for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

How you are running the Main class is causing the problem.

As you said, I have created jar called **ext1.jar** with ExternalObject and InternalObjct class files inside it.
And created **ext.jar** with Main and InternalObject class files.

If I run the following command, it throws Exception as you mentioned

> java -classpath .;C:
>   \path\to\ext.jar test.inside.Main

But, If I run the following command, it runs fine without any Exception

> java -classpath .;C:
>   \path\to\ext1.jar;C:
>   \path\to\ext.jar test.inside.Main

Comment: Well, as I said, I want to load the classes "dynamically", which means it can't be included in the -classpath option. Thanks anyway.